# Doubly Linked List Big Three

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, doubly-linked-list, assignment-operator

I am having a lot of trouble trying to get my copy constructor, destructor, and assignment operator working for a double linked list.
I have a class called dlist and a node class. The Node class contains a private node of next and previous and a data field. I am really stuck and I just can not for the life of me understand how to get these to work. If someone even just points out what's wrong. Sometimes I get a seg fault and other times I get a backtrace, depending on what I change in the big three.

```
//Destructor
template<class T>
dlist<T>::~dlist(){
    node<T> *rmptr = head;
    while(head != NULL && head != tail){
        head = head -> next();
        delete rmptr;
    }
}

//Copy Constructor
template <class T>
dlist<T>::dlist(const dlist<T>& other)
{
    if(other.head == NULL){
        head = new node<T>;
        tail -> set_next(head);
    }
    else{
        head = new node<T>(other.head -> data());
        tail = new node<T>;
        head -> set_next(tail);
        tail -> set_previous(head);
        node<T> *source = other.head -> next();
        node<T> *destination = head;
        while(source != NULL && source != other.tail){
            tail -> set_next(new node<T>);
            destination -> set_next(tail);
            tail -> set_data(source -> data());
            tail = tail -> next();
            source = source -> next();
        }
    }

}

//Assignment Operator
template<class T>
dlist<T>& dlist<T>::operator =(const dlist& other){

    if(this == &other){
        return *this;
    }
    node<T> * rmptr;
    while(head != NULL){
        rmptr = head;
        head = head -> next();
        delete rmptr;
    }
    head = tail = NULL;

    node<T> *source, *destination;
    if(other.head != NULL){
        head = new node<T>(other.head -> data());
        tail = new node<T>;
        head -> set_next(tail);
        tail -> set_previous(head);
        node<T> *source = other.head -> next();
        node<T> *destination = head;
        while(source != NULL && source != other.tail){
            tail -> set_next(new node<T>);
            destination -> set_next(tail);
            tail -> set_data(source -> data());
            tail = tail -> next();
            source = source -> next();
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Honestly, there are several things wrong with this code even before you get to the copy-semantics. Ex:  The destructor repeatedly deletes the *same pointer* (`rmptr`, initialized as the list head), and leaks the rest of the memory allocated for the list (assuming you didn't crash, which is highly likely).

Comment: I appreciate your input to. It was helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This copy/assignment/constructor/destructor pattern is a classic (at least by my standards :))

- First, you have to set `head` and `tail` to `NULL` (or `nullptr`) to avoid segfaults if objects are just created and unused. That avoids that destructor reads an uninitialized `head`. `NULL` prevents the destructor from doing something harmful
- Second: create a `destroy` utility method used by the destructor (of course) and also by the assignment operator to free assigned object (else you get memory leaks). No need to copy/paste the same code. And I was first assuming that your deletion code was ok, but it's not.

`destroy` would look like this (fixed the the help of WhozCraig comment):

```
template<class T>
void dlist<T>::destroy()
{
    node<T> *rmptr;
    while(head != NULL && head != tail){
        rmptr = head;
        head = head -> next();
        delete rmptr;

    }
    head = tail = NULL; // set head to NULL again

}
```

destructor just looks like this:

```
template<class T>
dlist<T>::~dlist(){
   destroy();
}
```

- Third create a `copy` utility method used by the copy constructor and the assignment operator (they share a lot of identical code, no need to copy/paste)

The `copy` method looks like this:

```
template <class T>
void dlist<T>::copy(const dlist<T>& other)
{
    if(other.head == NULL){
        head = new node<T>;
        tail -> set_next(head);
    }
    else{
        head = new node<T>(other.head -> data());
        tail = new node<T>;
        head -> set_next(tail);
        tail -> set_previous(head);
        node<T> *source = other.head -> next();
        node<T> *destination = head;
        while(source != NULL && source != other.tail){
            tail -> set_next(new node<T>);
            destination -> set_next(tail);
            tail -> set_data(source -> data());
            tail = tail -> next();
            source = source -> next();
        }
    }

}
```

You can now implement your copy constructor & assignment operator very simply:

```
template<class T>
dlist<T>::dlist(const dlist<T>& other)
{
    copy(other);
}

//Assignment Operator
template<class T>
dlist<T>& dlist<T>::operator =(const dlist& other){

    if(this == &other){
        return *this;
    }
    destroy();
    copy(other);

    return *this;
}
```

You won't have any memory leaks when assigning an object into another already "full" (aka allocated) object, and you won't get a segfault from freeing unallocated area because on a new object `head` and `tail` are `NULL`.

I apologize for answering "beyond" the question, but this pattern is very useful, and untrained coders who attempt to code low-level classes like this always stumble on the same memory-leak/crash/copy-paste hurdles.

Comment: Bless your soul! Thank you so much!

Comment: @KevinSwagger or use a [copy/swap idiom model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Comment: @WhozCraig and I thought I was smart! thanks for that. Very interesting.